# base64 image into JTextPane

Tags: java, image, base64, jtextpane

Is it possible to display a base64 encrypted image into a JTextPane ?

Here my code

```
JTextPane jTextPane = new JTextPane();

javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit eKit = new javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit();
jTextPane.setEditorKit(eKit);

jTextPane.setContentType("text/html");

// my base64 image, used then in the img tag in the html...
String img64="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhMAAwAPAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAMAAwAAAC8IyPqcvt3wCcDkiLc7C0qwyGHhSWpjQu5yqmCYsapyuvUUlvONmOZtfzgFzByTB10QgxOR0TqBQejhRNzOfkVJ+5YiUqrXF5Y5lKh/DeuNcP5yLWGsEbtLiOSpa/TPg7JpJHxyendzWTBfX0cxOnKPjgBzi4diinWGdkF8kjdfnycQZXZeYGejmJlZeGl9i2icVqaNVailT6F5iJ90m6mvuTS4OK05M0vDk0Q4XUtwvKOzrcd3iq9uisF81M1OIcR7lEewwcLp7tuNNkM3uNna3F2JQFo97Vriy/Xl4/f1cf5VWzXyym7PHhhx4dbgYKAAA7";

jTextPane.setText(html);
```

Comment: @Nicolas: I reformatted your question, could you please check if the image source is correct?

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is parse the Base64 encoded image into a byte array, then load an image using a ByteArrayIn,putStream using that byte array.

As an example, for decoding Base64, you can use [javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter#parseBase64Binary](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.5/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseBase64Binary(java.lang.String))

Comment: // ok thank you i used this:

 public static byte[] decode(String str){
    byte[] bt = null;
    try {   
            sun.misc.BASE64Decoder decoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder();
            bt = decoder.decodeBuffer( str );
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

            return bt;
    }
// and then
 byte [] parseImg = f.decode(texte);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(parseImg, "asd");
        jTextPane.insertIcon(image);

// but it doesn't dislay the image..could you help me ?

Comment: Well, without more infos, it will be hard to help you. Anyway, since there is no exception showing, I guess the Base64 decoder worked fine. As a consequence, issue come from the image icon creation. According to ImageIcon constructor documentation, iamge should be " containing a supported image format, such as GIF, JPEG, or (as of 1.3) PNG" Is it your case ?

Answer (score 1):

I found out!

solution is to 
extend the HTMLEditorKit by overriding the
getViewFactory in class javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit
then rewrite in the ImageViewclass.java the loadImage method 
to support images base64 encoded!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I also found out where I have to override, "loadimage" method. I should add conditional flow of [src="foo"] to load image, would be just image's link or image data itself. Now, all I'd write "JTextPane.setEditorKit(new MyExtendedHtmlEditorKit());".

However, my problem is here. the method exists "ImageViewer.class create()[HtmlFactory.class(static inner class)[HtmlEditorKit.class]] > void loadImage()[ImageViewer.class]" 
That's deep nested ,those class have many object invisible from outside class and many static definition. So, this means I must build a whole tree from roots for just pick a leaf on the top of branch. I can't edit Java VM runtime directly, compile and distribute it. I think this is IMPOSSIBLE, at least It's for sure for me!